# GitHub Codespaces show new changes in pull request on left side

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, pull-request, codespaces

Is it possible to switch the side on which the new changes of a pull request show up? I'm not that familiar with Visual Studio Code itself, but I love to use Codespaces to got through pull request and it annoys me that new content is shown on the right side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to a be setting to switch the order of the views for the extension.

One thing you can do is switch it to an inline view by setting the option from the top right ellipsis in Visual Studio Code while the editor is open:

[image]

The will merge the two views together and display it as it would look like on GitHub's website.